# Set actual text padding in TextView with compound drawables

Tags: android, textview, padding, compound-drawables

I have a `ListView` populated with an `ArrayAdapter`. For items I use just a single `TextView` layout. I want some of the rows to have compound drawables set.

Question: is there a way to set padding for the actual text that is contained in `TextView` so that the compound drawables don't get the padding too? Other solution would be to lock the width of text. Do I need to add `ImageViews` to my layout?

Comment: I'm curious about this too, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Nah. I just added some `ImageView`s and that was my solution. I even got a `Tumbleweed` badge for this question so I guess it's impossible.

Comment: Hah, funny.  I do see a way to put padding on the image, but not padding on the text.

Comment: Which way is that? I think `setCompoundDrawables` method gives you that option please let me know your solution.

Comment: txtView.setCompoundDrawablePadding (int pad);  or  your can set the bounds on your image and then use setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds.  I'm playing with them now to see how they work out!

Comment: Well, why don't you try setting a positive padding to the whole `TextView` and then set a negative padding to the drawable. That would make the text shifted and image on it's own place. I don't have access to my computer ATM so I can't test it.

Comment: That does seem like it would work, I guess you've answered your own question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I'm posting this as an answer so that someone, who comes across this post finds the answer.*

There's no direct way to set a padding only to text, but you can set a **positive** padding to the whole `TextView` and set a **negative** padding for the drawable.

Answer (score 50):

Quite simple:

```
android:drawablePadding="5dp"
```

It will automatically use the padding according to the direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already solved my problem then and I don't have source to try out your method.

Comment: And just for reference the method is `setCompoundDrawablePadding`

Answer (score 9):

Improving on Gio's sugestion, which is probably for a dated API/SDK...

TL:DR - just apply [`android:drawablePadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawablePadding) to increase distance between image and text.

Explanation:
[`android:drawablePadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawablePadding) now applies padding between `CompoundDrawable` and original `View`, in this case the TextView containing the text;

`android:padding`  and modifiers now apply to the whole group, including all compounds.

Doing the negative-positive hack doesn't seem to work no more.

So depending on the drawable position (drawableTop/Left/...), the padding will apply in the opposite direction of it, right next to the drawable, in other words between the two elements. For instance, Applying `drawablePadding="10dp"` to a left placed drawable would have a similar effect as setting an individual `ImageView` to the left of the TextView with `paddingRight="10dp"` (at least padding-wise).

Comment: I guess it was for a dated SDK, I also wanted to have some legacy support. At that time I couldn't think of a better solution than I posted.